# Security for Exposing Internal Web-based application to the World

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, security

We have an internal CRM system which is currently a website that can only be accessed inside our intranet. The boss is now wanting to have it exposed to the outside world so that people can use it from home and on the road. My concern is security based in the fact we will be exposing our Customer base to the outside world. I have implemented 3 layers of security as follows:

1. User Name and Strong password combination to login
2. SSL on all data being pushed across the line
3. Once the user is logged in and authenticated the server passes them a token which must be used in all communication with the server from than on.

Basically Im a bit of newb in the respect of web security. Can anyone give me advice on whether I am missing anything? Or something should be changed?

Comment: If it is being exposed, but should ONLY be used by employed personnel, why not consider adding VPN access to the network. Then the website itself is not "exposed".

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole world of stuff you should consider, and it'll be really hard to quickly answer this - so I'll point you at a range of resources that should help you out / get you started.

First, I'll plug http://security.stackexchange.com, for any specific questions you have - they could be a great help.

Now, on to more immediate things you should check:

1. Are your systems behind a firewall? I'd recommend at least your DB is placed on a server that is not directly available to the outside world.
2. Explore and run a range of (free) security tools against your site to try and find any problems. e.g.:
   https://asafaweb.com
   http://sectools.org/
3. Read up on common exploits (e.g. SQL injection) and make sure you are guarding against them:
   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main
   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability
4. How is your token being passed around, and what happens to it if another user gets hold of it (e.g. after it being cached on another machine)?
5. Make sure you have a decent password protection policy (decent complexity, protects against brute force attacks by locking accounts after 3 attempts).
6. If this is a massive concern for you (consider the risk to your business in a worst case scenario) consider getting an expert in, or someone to run a security test against your systems?

Or, as mrunion excellently points out in the comments above (+1), have you considered other more secure ways of opening this up, so that you don't need to publish this on the web?

Hope that gets you started.